# Finding substring in perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I want to check whether the string is present in xml tag

and xml tag is in the below format.

```
<admin var="s_admin">xyz</admin>
```

I tried with

```
index($xmlString,$str) != -1
```

but it is not working for me. Here is my code:

```
my $hostname = hostname;
my $wlsadmin = grep s_wls_admin_host $ENV{CONTEXT_FILE};
$wlsadmin=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
if(index($wlsadmin,$hostname) != -1) {
    print("True");
}
print($hostname);
print($wlsadmin);
```

And here is the value of print statement:

```
 rws3510357 <wls_admin_host oa_var="s_wls_admin_host">rws3510357</wls_admin_host>
```

Comment: Well, it works for me. Can you show us more code? A [working example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the alleged behaviour?

Comment: If you're tagging this question with `xml-parsing`, have you considered using an XML parser?

Comment: I am beginner in perl and iam not sure how to use xml parsing with it

Comment: What do you mean by `not working for me`? Can you show the code where you are using it?

Comment: @amon 
        my $hostname = `hostname`;

        my $wlsadmin = `grep s_wls_admin_host $ENV{CONTEXT_FILE}`;

        $wlsadmin=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

        if(index($wlsadmin,$hostname) != -1)

        {
                print("True");
        }

        print($hostname);
        print($wlsadmin);

And here is the value of print statement
rws3510357
<wls_admin_host oa_var="s_wls_admin_host">rws3510357</wls_admin_host>

Comment: This code works for me. After substituting `$hostname = 'rws3510357'; $wlsadmin = ' <wls_admin_host oa_var="s_wls_admin_host">rws3510357</wls_admin_host> ';` it prints `True`.

Comment: Thanks Rob I figured it out why index was not working for me. This Hostname command was appending a newline which i was not removing so index was not able to match it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong for you, but here is an example using a DOM-based XML parser to find the tag and extract its contents. From there its easy to compare those contents with some string as you have done using `index`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(<<'END');
<wls_admin_host oa_var="s_wls_admin_host">rws3510357</wls_admin_host>
END

my $hostname = 'rws3510357';

my $wlsadmin = $dom->at('wls_admin_host')->text;

if (index($wlsadmin, $hostname) != -1 ) {
  print "True\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a cool parser. BTW: using `at` instead of `find->[0]` could be a little bit more elegant. :)

Comment: Perhaps you are right, I think I misunderstood how `at` worked. It seems like internally that's all it does. Will change.

Comment: Thanks memowe and Joel for showing how to achieve the same using parser